# Can I build Mobile App using PhoneGap for a Application build using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html

Can I build a Hybrid Mobile App using PhoneGab or Telerik for an application built using PHP and MySQL running on AWS or any Hosting platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PhoneGap you can only use HTML / CSS / JavaScript.

However if you have an app you built using PHP / MySQL you can connect to it within your PhoneGap application via ajax.

So the answer to your question is yes, you can build a mobile app for your application built using PHP and MySQL.